# ASP.NET FormsAuthentication: have to log in again when restarting application

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET application using FormsAuthentication. Whenever I restart the application or web server, my authentication token is invalid and I have to log in again. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By default, FormsAuthentication validates authentication data on every request by having the client store an encrypted copy of the data. The encryption key is stored in `Machine.config`. The specific key to use is in `<machineKey decryptionKey="YOUR KEY HERE">`.

If you do not provide a decryption key, one is automatically generated on application startup. Since it is randomly generated, it will be different each time you restart the application. On the validation phase, FormsAuthentication attempts to decrypt the authentication data and fails. Then the user is no longer logged in.

There are two ways of resolving this problem.

- Providing a machineKey in `Machine.config` will give FormsAuthentication a consistent key to use, so validation will succeed with the encrypted cookie from previous application runs.
- Using `<forms protection="None" ... />` in Web.config will disable authentication data encryption and validation. This is insecure and only appropriate for development, since it will be trivial for users to impersonate each other.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. MSDN concurs : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx Specifically look at **Configuring <machineKey> to Encrypt Forms Authentication Tickets**

Answer (score 1):

The default session state mode in asp.net is in-proc (cached in-memory) unless you specify otherwise. When the application shuts down, memory is cleared and the in-proc session cache is therefore lost.

@dhasenan The machinekey config will only be an issue if the application is deployed across a web farm or the cloud. The idea of overriding the machine-level config of the Machinekey element is to ensure that multiple machines are using the exact same keys.

Therefore, the machine key shouldn't be an issue because if one is not provided at the application level, the machine key in the machine.config will be used instead, which is persisted and static, so it will not be regenerated between sessions.